# Adding fields from a many-to-many relationship to a Django Admin Inline

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, many-to-many

I am trying to set up a project where I have user, questions for the users, and then the answers that the users give.  Here are my models.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.TextField()
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    question = models.ManyToManyField(Question)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

Then in the admin I would like to be able to click on a user and see their answers so I set my admin up like so.

```
class AnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Answer.user.through

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'email')
    inlines = [AnswerInline]

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('question',)

class AnswerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('answer', )
    fields = ('question', 'answer',)

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
admin.site.register(Answer, AnswerAdmin)
```

However, when viewing users it only shows their answer.  It doesn't show the question that answer is associated with.  How do I add this information to the admin page in a way that makes sense.  Preferably with the question first and then the answer to that question to the right of it.

**Update**
I added this to the admin inline, however it shows up blank.  So I still need it to show the actual string that is the "question"

```
class AnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Answer.user.through
    fields = ('question', 'answer')
    readonly_fields = ('question',)
    extra = 0

    def question(self, obj):
        q = self.question.question
        return q
```

Comment: Why question and user are many to many fields? I think you meant to use the `ForeignKey` instead.

Comment: You are correct.  I set these up completely wrong and should have used foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I set up the models incorrectly.  Here is how they should look.

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField(default=None)
    people = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Answer')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

and then here is the admin that works.

```
class AnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Answer
    fields = ('question', 'answer')
    readonly_fields = ('question', 'answer')
    extra = 0

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'email')
    inlines = [AnswerInline]

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('question',)

class AnswerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('answer',)
    fields = ('question', 'answer', 'user')
```